# How to get the exact query generated by the ODBC driver

Tags: reporting-services, odbc, impala, cloudera-quickstart-vm

We are connecting Hadoop cloudera CDH distribution through ODBC driver. Queries are generated from SSRS. Few queries are working fine with parameters augmented through ? placeholder. Few other queries with parameters augmented through ? are not executing.
Error [HY000][Cloudera][ImpalaODBC] (100) error while executing a query in Impala[HY000] : AnalysisException : syntax error in line 1 where Date >= ? and Date <= ?
^Encountered : Unexpected characterExpected : Case... Exception : syntax error.
If i remove where Date >= ? and Date <= ? or supply the hard coded value then query is working perfect.
Few other queries with same filter are working perfect.

1. What should be recommended investigation points?
2. Where could i get the exact impala transformed query to investigate whether query is generated correct or not ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options:

- /var/log/impalad/audit stores audit logs (at least in CDH). Those logs contain sql_statement field that stores executed sql queries
- Impala has a web server running on a 25000 port. You could connect
  with your browser and see queries executed (/queries tab).
- If you are using Cloudera Manager, you could see all executed impala 
  queries in "impala/queries"

Comment: /var/log/impalad/audit  directory is empty. how to enable logging sql queries?